# Get specific column with tFileInputExcel in Talend

Tags: java, talend

[image]How can I get just column number 1 and 4 from my excel file using tFileInputExcel ? I found how to specify the sheet, but not the column! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a tFileInputExcel and a tFilterColumn just after.

So, in the tFilterColumn you can choose the row you keep.

Answer (score 1):

You could also extract all the columns and only output the ones you want using tMap.